# C++17 iterator_traits didn't called

Tags: c++, c++17

I am new to the customized C++17 iterator after it has changed some features. To illustrate error, the following is a minimalist code to illustrate the issue. Error was reported that

> auto[min_it, max_it] = std::minmax_element(r.begin(), r.end());

which can't find the

> forward_iterator_tag

Why does this happen? How we can fix it? Many thanks!!

```
#include <iostream>

class num_iterator {
 public:
  explicit num_iterator(int pos = 0) : i{pos} {};
  int operator*() const {
      return i;
  }
  num_iterator &operator++() {
      ++i;
      return *this;
  }
  bool operator!=(const num_iterator &other) {
      return i != other.i;
  }
 private:
  int i;
};

class num_range {
 public:
  num_range(int from, int to) : a{from}, b{to} {};
  num_iterator begin() {
      return num_iterator{a};
  }
  num_iterator end() {
      return num_iterator{b};
  }
 private:
  int a{0};
  int b{0};
};


namespace std {
template<>
struct iterator_traits<num_iterator> {
  using iterator_cateory = std::forward_iterator_tag;
  using value_type = int;
};
}

int main() {
    for (int a:num_range(10, 20)) {
        std::cout << a << " ";
    }

    num_range r{100, 110};

    auto[min_it, max_it] = std::minmax_element(r.begin(), r.end());
    std::cout << *min_it << std::endl;
    std::cout << *max_it << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this specific case, the compiler is complaining about a lack of `operator==` for your custom iterator:

```
  bool operator==(const num_iterator& other){
      return !(*this != other);
  }
```

The other specific issue is that you misspelled `iterator_category`

```
using iterator_category = std::forward_iterator_tag;
```

In general, defining your own iterator is not always very straightforward. There are a number of required operations that vary depending on your iterator type. I recommend using [Boost.Iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/index.html) to do it right.

The [counting iterator](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/libs/iterator/doc/counting_iterator.html) solves your problem already.

A forward iterator requires a number of other things you haven't provided, for example:

- you are missing type traits for `pointer`, `difference_type`, and the type trait for `reference` must be `const T&`
- you need both prefix *and* postfix increment operators
- you need both `operator==` *and* `operator!=` (as stated above)
- you are also missing `operator->`

### [Demo](https://wandbox.org/permlink/StYTNGBQcwNp34hg)

Comment: did I miss something? It seems didn't work even I add it.

Comment: I copy paste the demo, here is error message... /XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/algorithm:2632:19: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::minmax_element<num_iterator, std::__1::__less<int, int> >' requested here
    return _VSTD::minmax_element(__first, __last,
                  ^
/Temp/CPPPlayground/main.cpp:54:31: note: in instantiation of function template specialization 'std::__1::minmax_element<num_iterator>' requested here
  auto[min_it, max_it] = std::minmax_element(r.begin(), r.end());